# Placing cursor (blinking caret) into input TextField for user input in AS3.

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

What is an easiest way to place cursor (focus?) into a `Input` TextField receiving user input after an event?  Focus Manager classes have always seems very confusing to me.

Answer (score 4):

Good news for you: in as3 there is no Focus Manager, just use the stage:

```
stage.focus = textField;
textField.setSelection(textField.text.length,textField.text.length); //place caret at end of text
```

Comment: Just as an aside (not a criticism of your answer which is good), there is a FocusManager class I think, but it's for components and not appropriate here. I think that confuses people if they're browsing the AS3 language reference.

Comment: The issue might lay in IDE, try using this solution in production enthronement. Try using compiled .swf file in browser or any another player.